# SQL - Dervied Foreign Key - Possible?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm just curious if this is possible, specifically in SQL CE (Express) with support in .NET's Entity Framework:

```
Table1 (primary)
-nvarchar(2000) url
-...

Table2 (with foreign key)
-nvarchar(2000) domain
-...
```

**foreign key on Table2.domain references Table1.url such that Table.url contains Table2.domain**

e.g.

```
Table1:
http://www.google.com/blah/blah
http://www.cnn.com/blah/
http://www.google.com/foo

Table2:
google.com
cnn.com
```

Is it possible for this to be scripted and enforced by SQL CE (let alone any relation database) and, if so, can .NET's Entity Framework automatically support this if I import my database into a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the whole foreign key value must match the whole primary key value in the referenced table.

I'm trying to think of something helpful to suggest.

- You could validate the strings in table2 using a trigger or a check constraint, but this involves writing meticulous expressions that are easy to get wrong.
- You could store the domain redundantly in table1, put a `UNIQUE` constraint on it, and declare your foreign key in table2 to point to the table1.domain.  Foreign key constraints can reference columns in a unique constraint as well as columns in a primary key constraint.